# Задание из егэ. Не понимаю что не правильно. PYTHON

Tags: python

В файле содержится последовательность из 10 000 целых положительных чисел. Каждое число не превышает 10 000. Определите и запишите в ответе сначала количество пар элементов последовательности, у которых сумма нечётна, а произведение делится на 3, затем максимальную из сумм элементов таких пар. В данной задаче под парой подразумевается два различных элемента последовательности. Порядок элементов в паре не важен.[Задание и доп файл](https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=37350)

```
with open('17.txt') as f:
numbers = [int(x) for x in f]
s = []
for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
    if (numbers[i] * numbers[i-1]) % 3 == 0 and (numbers[i] + numbers[i-1]) % 2 != 0:
        s.append(numbers[i] + numbers[i-1])
print(len(s), max(s))
```

Comment: в следующий раз нужно прямо в вопросе писать почему ты решил, что что-то неправильно.

Comment: Считать каждую пару - бред голимый. Раздели за один проход все числа на 4 группы. Делится/не делится на 3 и чётное/нечётное. А потом посчитай количество комбинаций, и макс. суммы для каждой пары групп.

Answer (score 1):

Пара это не только два соседних числа, но и каждая комбинация из любых двух чисел.

Comment: Я только что сам понял. Но пока что не получается реализовать.

Comment: В простейшем случае - использовать второй вложенный цикл (долго будет)

Comment: если второй цикл использовать не с начала, а с текущего элемента внешнего цикла, то будет примерно вполовину быстрее

Comment: @Эникейщик Да даже целиком цикл в цикле 2 минуты в Google Colab занимает, терпимо, не так уж долго )

Comment: Дожили. В задании даже приводится решение (хоть и на другом языке), и просто переписать его на Питон - уже непосильная задача.

Comment: @GrAnd Кстати, да. Там ещё и оптимально сделано в плане того, что список не хранится, а считается количество и максимум на ходу.

Comment: @GrAnd думаю, автор хотел решить самостоятельно, а не переписать готовое

Comment: @MBo Кстати, если обернуть эти цикл в цикле в `Numba`, то выполнится за 1 секунду )

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну вообще задача решается за линейное время при хранении количества и максимальных чётных и нечетных чисел с остатками 0 и не ноль по модулю 3

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [int(x) for x in open('17.txt') ]
count = mac = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
    if (a[i ]-a[j] )% 2 == 0 and (a[i ]% 31 == 0 or a[j ]% 31 
  == 0):
        count+=1
        if a[i]+a[j]>mac:
            mac=a[i]+a[j]
  print(count,mac)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]